# Why SQL Server Reporting Services only showing MS SQL Server as only available Data Source?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

When I try to create a new data source in SSRS web browser, the only available connection type avaiable is MS SQL Server. Why is it not showing other sources.
Although I've already installed Oracle and it's required drivers.

What could be the issue ?

[Screenshot of Data Sources available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEJNw.png)

Comment: SSRS is .NET Framework based, what drivers did you install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to the question is that SQL Server Reporting Services is no longer compatible with newer Windows Server Machines hence all the issues.

So, I installed Power BI Reporting Services (PBIRS) instead of SSRS. and everything works fine now.